# Can i use one github account in several railway accounts?

Tags: github, deployment, railway

I don't know if i can use one account in just one of several railway accounts, i did'nt test because i am afraid of only one be allowed. I am a web programmer and i'm develop a website for a family member.

The railway acceps a not new github account for validation and deployment.